# Create unique indexes for document's objects stored in an array

Tags: mongodb

How do one create unique indexes for document's objects stored in array?

```
{
_id: 'documentId',
books: [
  {
    unique_id: 1,
    title: 'Asd',
  },
  {
    unique_id: 2,
    title: 'Wsad',
  }
  ...
 ] 
}
```

One thing I can think of is autoincrementing. Or is there any *mongo way* to do so?

Comment: You said unique indexes then auto increment. I am confused. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What I want is for every *book* in my *books[]* to have one separated unique property, so I can tell one from another. Consider "*Javascript manual*" in the library document for example, with another property *library_front_window*, array storing `unique_id` of let's say three of seven exisiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you remove the `_id` field from your doc, `mongo` will automatically add one for you, which is:

1. guaranteed to be unique
2. contains the timestamp of creation
3. lots of other features.

see here: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/ObjectId/

Looking at the example object again, are you referring to the ids in the books array?
If so, you can assign them with ObjectIds as well, just like in the document root's _id field:

```
doc.books.forEach(x => { x.unique_id = new ObjectId() } );
```

Comment: Right, but what I want to achieve is to have my unique id on **both** document and it's array's objects. It isn't there for no reason :).

Comment: So, given the situation when I `updateOne()` my document and `$push` to the (books) array, what I need to do is simply update the data being pushed (single book) with new property `new ObjectId()` ?

Comment: yes, when creating that new book entry, just assign `new ObjectId()` to your id field, BTW, it's common practice to use `_id` as the name of the field, even for internal objects, so I'd create it as `{ _id : new ObjectId(), title: 'hello' }`

Comment: All right, thank you very much sir! It works **perfectly**, just like you said :).